# unit test module import throws undefined symbol error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to import my class using this code

```swift
import XCTest
@testable import Test2

class Tests_iOS: XCTestCase {
    var test2:TestModule2!
    
    override func setUp() {
        let test2 = TestModule2()
    }
}
```

however xcode is throwing undefined symbol error

```
Undefined symbol: nominal type descriptor for Test2.TestModule2
Undefined symbol: type metadata accessor for Test2.TestModule2
Undefined symbol: Test2.TestModule2.__allocating_init() -> Test2.TestModule2
```

This doesn't happen with my older xcode 11 code using UIKit.

[image]

what is the cause of this error and how can I import modules correctly.

system specification

```
Mac M1 16GB
OS: Big Sur 11.4
Xcode: Version 13.0 beta (13A5154h)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you created a multiplatform project, turns out that the default test target is a UI test and not a unit test.
Try adding a new test target of type unit test.
See this answer: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/665120